# How to add helix effect on flip effect in CSS?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I've created this flip card but I'm wondering if is a way to add in CSS helix effect when it's flipping, or an effect like twist the image.

here I have my flip card demo
http://jsfiddle.net/7k1sf8qk/

and here is my CSS code

```
.flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -o-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 970px;
    height: 250px;
}

.flipper {
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -o-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -ms-transition: 0.6s;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;


    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

.flip-container:hover .back, .flip-container.hover .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.flip-container:hover .front, .flip-container.hover .front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}


.front {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by helix effect? Do you want 2 halves of the image flipping in opposite directions?

Comment: i was looking on this but it generate the image and what I want to make is something bigger than this..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't recreate this effect using the markup you currently have in place.

What I would recommend is setting the image as the background for a large number of set height HTML elements which you can then set inline styles for with JavaScript to manage the helix effect.

I've made a quick codepen which will hopefully show what I mean:

http://codepen.io/jazibobs/pen/wMvwKP

```css
body {
  background: #555;
}

ul {
  background: #fff;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/600/600);
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
          transition: transform 2s ease;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
  background-position: 0 -200px;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
  background-position: 0 -400px;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
          transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
ul:hover li {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```